# Multiple processes on Single SQS with in a Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

Currently , we have a sqs subscribed to a Standard SNS topic which triggers a lambda to publish some data based upon these events to a downstream X .

We have come with another usecase where we want to listen to this exiting SNS and publish another set of data based on these events to downstream Y . In future we might have another use case where we want to listen to this exiting SNS and publish another set of data based on these events to downstream Z .

I was wondering if we can re use this existing SQS and lambda for these new use case . I am just curious how wan we handle failure scenarios in case one of publish fails . Failure of 1 process out of x will lead the message back to DLQ from where the re drive would be required , so all the consumer processes of this message with in the lambda will have again process this redrived message ?

Another way could be have a separate SQS and separate lambda for each of such use cases .

has someone had a similar problem statement and what was the approach followed out of the above two or anything that could help reusing some of the existing infra ?

Answer (score 0):

You should **subscribe multiple Amazon SQS queues to the Amazon SNS topic**, so that each of them receives a copy of the message. Each SQS queue can have its own Dead Letter Queue for error handling.

It is also possible to subscribe the AWS Lambda function to the Amazon SNS topic *directly*, without using an Amazon SQS queue. The Lambda function can [send failed messages directly to a Dead Letter Queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html#invocation-dlq).